# React Native Gorhom bottom sheet property value of undefined

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

I want to create a swipeable and content based height bottom Sheet for my react native app. So I use gorhom bottom sheet but it shows error propety value of undefined exactly at animatedIndex.value i think so have a look at full code [GORHOM BOTTOM SHEET](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/custom-handle)

BottomSheet.tsx

```
  const containerStyle = useMemo(() => [styles.header, style], [style]);
  const containerAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const borderTopRadius = interpolate(
      animatedIndex.value,
      [1, 2],
      [20, 0],
      Extrapolate.CLAMP
    );
    return {
      borderTopLeftRadius: borderTopRadius,
      borderTopRightRadius: borderTopRadius,
    };
  });
  const leftIndicatorStyle = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...styles.indicator,
      ...styles.leftIndicator,
    }),
    []
  );
```

I just import a bottom Sheets in my Main App.js file

App.js

```
<GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <BottomSheets/>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
```